# In sitecore, after I created and published a web form, it don't appear in the site

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

I've created a few web forms (WFFM) in Page Editor (Tell a friend and 2 blank forms), but they don't appear in the site after I published them.  What can it be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to publish all items related to WFFM module? Please check layouts,templates if are published. This is usual issue, templates or layouts/sublayouts are not published

Comment: all layouts, templates are published

Comment: I publish everything - all changes appear in the site, except forms

Comment: Have you set up a validate placeholder for the form and linked the form to it?

Comment: Have you check for any errors in logs?

Comment: Can you see forms in Preview or in Page Editor? If yes, can you check please if you have workflow assign to the item where you have inserted the form.

Comment: yes, I've set up a placeholder for form and linked the form to it.There are no errors in logs.

Comment: yes, I can see forms in Preview and in Page Editor, I've assigned workflow to the item, but still nothing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can see this form in the page editor but not on your website this is pointing out it has something to do with publishing. Try to open your environment in Desktop mode (when login in u can select it) and re-check if u can see all the items in the web database. For example if your placeholder settings are not published you will find this behavior to happen. Recheck all items that need to be published (layouts / sublayouts / placeholder settings / form itself / form fields etc.) and that should solve your problem.

Comment: yeah, thank you - the problem was with FormId and I haven't published modules